# ASP.NET Dynamic-data: Hot to add editable text column to readonly grid view

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

For displaying data in our application I've use GridView with the following markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="listGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" 
AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"CssClass="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
<asp:DynamicField DataField="App_Contact" />
<asp:DynamicField DataField="OldContact" />
<asp:DynamicField DataField="OldContactType" />
<asp:DynamicField DataField="NewContact" />
<asp:DynamicField DataField="NewContactType" />
<asp:DynamicField DataField="action_id" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Control with above grid is used as List control and display data in read only mode.
I would like add text box for each row and button for text box values saving.
I've create dynamic filed control (inherited from `FieldTemplateUserControl`), but control always invoked in readonly mode and property `Mode` always equal `Read` and control does not save data in databound source.
May be is exists any another way to add editable column to dynamic data List control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDataBoundControl, IDataBoundListControl, IDataBoundItemControl and the IFieldControl interfaces expose the common properties that are required for Dynamic Data support. If you are creating a custom data-bound control that will work with Dynamic Data, you can implement these interfaces instead of deriving from the DataBoundControl class.